# Laravel 5 improper inferring of foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

According to Laravel 5 documentation,

> Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on
>   the Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case"
>   name of the owning model and suffix it with _id. So, for this example,
>   Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the Comment model is post_id.

This, however, is not the case in reality, because if one has:

```
// Class: Video
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

then calling $video->author will not work, because Laravel will assume the foreign key to be author_id instead of user_id.

Am I missing anything or is this indeed a documentation error?

Answer (score 1):

You are posting the documentation for `hasMany`, not `belongsTo`.

For `belongsTo` it will look for `user_id` in the Video and match it against `id` on the User model. For `hasMany` it will look for the `id` in Video and match it against `video_id` in User, which makes no sense in this case.

`belongsTo` is the inverted version of `hasMany`.

EDIT: Yes. Sorry, you seem to be right. When I change the relationship function's name to `user` instead of `author` it works.

The only way to get around it easily is to pass `user_id` along as foreign key.

```
// Video
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

However, the documentation for `belongsTo` **does** state (You posted `hasMany`):

> *Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id*. However, if the foreign key on the Phone model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method

As I said in my original answer, you were looking at the incorrect part of the documentation.

Comment: You are not asnwering my question. Try the example I gave you and see that for belongsTo relations it will NOT look for user_id in the video but for author_id.

Comment: It cannot look for `author_id`, unless you have an Author model, changed a $primaryKey in the model to `author_id` or you manually pass it on in the relationship function, but in the example you post you do not. Either way, then your question is incomplete.

Comment: Did you try reproducing my scenario as stated? No $primaryKey or additional parameters needed. Just what is given in the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you seem to be correct. But as I said, you were looking at the wrong piece of documentation. Got me confused too. :) Updated my answer.

Comment: @Slavic did you figure it out? :)

Comment: Hey Ciccio, well - I figured out the problem of relationship definition ebfore I posted teh question. The question just asks whether this is a documentation issue